# Distinct after join or sub-query with distinct and then join

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-performance

While writing a procedure, I came across a situation were I have to put a `DISTINCT` in a query. This is somewhat similar to my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
     ID         INT,
     TypeID     INT,
     SubTypeID  INT,
     Name       VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

CREATE TABLE T2
(
     TypeID     INT,
     SubTypeID  INT,
     TypeName   VARCHAR(50)
);
GO

INSERT INTO T2 (TypeID, SubTypeID, TypeName)
VALUES (1, 1, 'AAA'), (1, 2, 'AAA'),
       (2, 1, 'BBB'), (2, 2, 'BBB'),
       (3, 1, 'CCC'), (3, 2, 'CCC');

INSERT INTO T1 (ID, TypeID, SubTypeID, Name)
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'ABC'), (2, 2, 2, 'BCD'),
       (3, 3, 2, 'CDE'), (4, 1, 1, 'DEF'),
       (5, 2, 2, 'EFG'), (6, 3, 0, 'FGH');    -- Sub Type not detected yet.
GO
```

In this, either user can provide the `SubType` or let the system to detect.

Now I have 2 query options for this scenario.

Option 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.TypeName
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.TypeID = T2.TypeID;
```

And Option 2

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.TypeName
FROM T1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT  TypeID, TypeName FROM T2) AS T2 ON T1.TypeID = T2.TypeID;
```

The result is same in both the cases but I want to know which should be preferred. There may be millions of rows in table T1 and thousands of rows in T2.

In my opinion, I should use the first option to avoid subquery.

But still want to confirm with the community as it may have some or major performance impact which is not known yet.

Comment: As with most performance related questions, you need to check the `execution plan` of the results to know for sure which query will do better.  Assuming `t1.Id` is a primary key, I presume they will have the same plan though.  With that said, those queries could produce different results depending on the data...

Comment: it depends on the size of join's result, if it's large enough then picking `distinct` from `T2` only would be faster than picking `distinct` from join. the second query would give a smaller set to join which again makes it faster compared to the first one

Comment: @mangusta Yes but the down side of that in my opinion is it will not get the benefits of Indexes applied on T2 or will it?

Comment: @sgeddes I know about the execution plan but I could not find any difference since I only have a very small amount of sample data and the product is yet to go in production. And about the different results, they will not since first table have to have only unique values. [deleted old comment and added new to tag sgeddes ]

Comment: have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042524/can-you-index-subqueries
in case of MySQL, the optimizer allows the index to be used on subquery result as well. however that might not be the case with MSSQL

Comment: @mangusta I have no idea if it works in MS-SQL and if doesn't, I'll have no options to know any sooner :(

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, avoid `select distinct` in the outer query.  I would try this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.TypeName
FROM T1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT DISTINCT T2.TypeName
      FROM T2
      WHERE T1.TypeID = T2.TypeID
     ) T2;
```